# Looking for way to get all elements of table with invoke-restmethod

Tags: powershell

i am looking for a way to get all elements of a table with around 1000 entries

i am able to get 10 elements that are "visible" on the website itself, but all the others are on more pages, which i cant read out with the invoke-restmethod command.

Is there a way to get all entries of the table?

```
# GET USERPROFILES

$basicAuthValue = "token $token"

$Headers1 = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://Url-that-im-using' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers1 -Body $body
$response2 | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Comment: If the page is only returning 10 elements, than you can only get 10 elements but perhaps you can share the url you are using? Chances are, you can alter the amount of results that are retrieved.

Comment: "which i cant read out with the invoke-restmethod command" - why? Does it throw and error when you try to request the next page?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - would you prefer more resource friendly code to more simple code? Genuine question because that's the major difference to me in your and my comment. *leaving aside that if millions of elements are involved, you practically have to use paging*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I prefer neither until I know what kind of API/website OP is working with :-)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers well if i look at the table online, i can see 951 entries

Comment: @VinBenzin - What is the URL to get tot he second page? Please take note that webscraping *(what you are doing)* comes in handy for one off situations but if it's your aim to implement this into a business process, you really should find another means. A report, API or anything *but* webscraping.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen well im an apprentice in IT and im working with Django REST Framework im sorry idk if that helps :-) oh and no, it doesn't throw any errors

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers im not trying to use it for websrcaping, in our company im sorta the only one knowing a bit about powershell, the secont url is only accessible by a token generated by the first, which im also using in my script

Comment: Fair enough but at this point, all I can see with what you've presented is that, yes it should be possible. At this point, best advice I can give yo is to open developer tools, navigate to some pages, right click on the requests of interest in the Network tab and copy all requests as Powershell.

Comment: If you have the way to get to page 2 already in your script, what is the actual issue? You should be able to get all results then? We can't really do much more for you without the actual code and at the very least some sanitized results from the first response (ideally the site though if public).